# How to read a text when it is not in any HTML tag

Tags: selenium, selenium-webdriver

How can I find text in following HTML:

```
style="background-color: transparent;">
<-a hre f="/">Home<-/ a>
<-a id="brea dcrumbs-790" class=" main active mainactive" href="/products">Products<-/a>
<-a href="/products/fruit-and-creme-curds">Fruit & Crème Curds<-/a>
Crème Banana Curd
<-/li>
<-/ul>"
</div>
```

This is HTML for Bread Crumb, first three are link and fourth is page name. I want to read page name `(Crème Banana Curd) from Bread crumb.` But since this is not in any node so how to catch it

Comment: hi plz post the html source code of the parents as well

Comment: Please correct your HTML format first...

Comment: <ul>
<li>
<a href="/">Home</a>
</li>
<li style="background-color: transparent;">
<a id="breadcrumbs-644" class=" main active mainactive" href="/products">Products</a>
<a href="/products/meat-sauce" style="background-color: transparent;">Meat Sauce</a>
Fish & Chip Vinegar
</li>
</ul>          This is another example.  html I add here gets converted into simple text or loose format. Now I want to read text "Fish & Chip Vinegar" which is dynamic content

Answer (score 0):

If the `text` isn't present inside any `tag`, then it is present in `body` tag:-

So you can use something like below to identify it:-

```
html/body/text()
```

Comment: when I use text() with my xpath I see error "error = TypeError: e.scrollIntoView is not a function"

Comment: Thats something different. You wouldn't get this error by using the above xpath

Answer (score 0):

Though the question seems to be vague without a proper HTML source but still you may try the solution below by storing the Text in a Variable-

```
 var breadcrumb = FindElement(By.XPath(".//*[@id='brea dcrumbs-790']/following-sibling::a")).Text;
```

Comment: I wish to find text 'Crème Banana Curd' which is dynamic. I think ur code will get me 'Fruit & Crème Curd'

Answer (score 0):

use the below code:

```
WebElement elem = driver.findElement(By.xpath("//*[contains(text(),'Crème Banana Curd')]"));

elem.getText();
```

hope this will help you.

Comment: I am supposed to read text 'Crème Banana Curd' and this value is dynamic and I need to find this value only. so cant use it